# How to use ifelse inside the for loop in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops, na

I have to check the names of all variables in a data.frame and if match found, need to replace the NA values in that variable with Median, else for others replace NAs with mean.

The data.frame cyl_spec has 11 variables and I have to replace NA as below:

1. Viscosity: Impute with median
2. Wax: Impute with median
3. Others: Impute with Mean

I can certainly do it by picking the variables one at a time but I was trying the following code :

```
attach(cyl_spec)
var <- colnames(cyl_spec)
for(val in var)
{
  if(val == 'viscosity'){viscosity[is.na(viscosity == T)] <- median(viscosity, na.rm = T)}
  else if(val == 'wax'){wax[is.na(wax == T)] <- median(wax, na.rm = T)}
  else {val[is.na(val == T)] <- mean(val, na.rm = T)}
}
detach(cyl_spec)
```

Somehow the code is not doing anything and I am still getting the same no of NA in the variable using this command :

```
sum(is.na(cyl_spec$viscosity)
```

Also, when I run this code I get the following warning message :

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(val, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(val, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(val, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(val, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In mean.default(val, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
6: In mean.default(val, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
7: In mean.default(val, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
8: In mean.default(val, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
9: In mean.default(val, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Could someone please help me with finding the solution for this, am stuck! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: For starters, don't ever use `attach`, where did you pick it up from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a loop to do this. Moreover, the correct syntax to test for na values is `is.na(var)`, not `is.na(var == TRUE)`. Finally, if you want to avoid typing the name of your dataframe, you would need to use some function that does it (like `with` or the `dplyr` functions). Here, R is looking for an object named `viscosity` that is nowhere to be found because it is the name of a column inside `cyl_spec` (same for the other variable names).

```
cyl_spec$viscosity[is.na(cyl_spec$viscosity)] <- median(cyl_spec$viscosity, na.rm = T)
cyl_spec$wax[is.na(cyl_spec$wax)] <- median(cyl_spec$wax, na.rm = T)
cyl_spec$val[is.na(cyl_spec$val)] <- mean(cyl_spec$val, na.rm = T)
```

If all you need is to deal with this data.frame and only those three variables, I strongly recommend you stick to this base-r solution. If, however, you are looking to do this on a data frame with more variables and you want to automate it, you could look into the `dplyr::mutate_each`. Here is an example with simulated data.

We create a data.frame with 7 variables and assign some NA values.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(n=runif(100),
                 m=runif(100),
                 d=runif(100),
                 o=runif(100),
                 e=runif(100),
                 f=runif(100),
                 g=runif(100))

df <- mutate_each(df,funs(ifelse(.>.8,NA,.)))

head(df)

           n          m         d           o         e          f         g
1 0.50747820 0.34434350 0.2230884 0.347860110        NA         NA        NA
2 0.30676851 0.06132255 0.5358950 0.007992606 0.6855115         NA 0.7478783
3 0.42690767 0.36897981 0.6625291 0.401344915 0.6296311         NA 0.7225419
4 0.69310208 0.40759356        NA 0.588350693 0.7508252 0.29063776 0.5457709
5 0.08513597         NA 0.1491831          NA        NA 0.07203601 0.2641231
6 0.22543662         NA 0.6700994 0.708542599 0.3600703 0.55888842 0.3057243
```

Now, we apply to each variable a function to infer NA values from either mean or median :

```
df <- df %>%
## Which variables are to be recoded with mean? here, n and m
  mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.),mean(.,na.rm = TRUE),.)),n,m) %>% 
## Which variables are to be recoded with median? here, d,o,e,f,g
  mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.),median(.,na.rm = TRUE),.)),d,o,e,f,g)

head(df)

           n          m         d           o         e          f         g
1 0.50747820 0.34434350 0.2230884 0.347860110 0.3602354 0.39956699 0.4499041
2 0.30676851 0.06132255 0.5358950 0.007992606 0.6855115 0.39956699 0.7478783
3 0.42690767 0.36897981 0.6625291 0.401344915 0.6296311 0.39956699 0.7225419
4 0.69310208 0.40759356 0.4407363 0.588350693 0.7508252 0.29063776 0.5457709
5 0.08513597 0.40892568 0.1491831 0.378731867 0.3602354 0.07203601 0.2641231
6 0.22543662 0.40892568 0.6700994 0.708542599 0.3600703 0.55888842 0.3057243
```

Comment: Thanks @scoa - Are you suggesting to you use these lines inside the for loop, if not, how do I define `val`. I wanted to use the columns at runtime and then do the computation based on the condition.

Comment: @RanjanPandey no, you can run those line outside of a loop. If you just need to replace NA values in three variables, the three lines I gave should be enough. If you are in a situation where you have multiple columns, and you don't know their names, then we should consider another solution ; in that case, I would favor `dplyr::mutate_each` over a loop.  If this is the case, please update your question to reflect that you are looking for a more general solution (how to infer NA with median/mean on n variables) and upload/create some example data.

Answer (score 0):

Though @scoa has already answered, if you still want to do this using a `for` loop, just get rid of the `attach` and `detach` functions, and do the following:

```
var <- names(cyl_spec)           #get column names
cols <- c('viscosity', 'wax')    #get the required columns
for(val in var) 
{ 
  #loop over the required columns.
  # Where it equals our required, use median, and mean elsewhere
  for(i in 1:length(cols))
    {
      if(is.element(cols[i], val))
        { 
           #get out rows with na values
           na_rows <- is.na(cyl_spec[, val])
           cyl_spec[na_rows,val] <- median(cyl_spec[,val], na.rm = T)
         }
      else
        {
          #get out rows with na values
          na_rows <- is.na(cyl_spec[, val])
          cyl_spec[na_rows,val] <- mean(cyl_spec[,val], na.rm = T)
        }
    }
}
```

...though as you can probably see, it's quite cumbersome. Strongly advise you directly input them as in your question and answer provided by @scoa, or when you have (way) more than 2 columns you want to change. (also look into using `mutate` function in `dplyr` package).

Comment: Thanks @Deolu : yeah it is cumbersome! I know the simple way of doing it, just thought of doing it in a loop and use the variables at runtime. Also, I have to find the names of variables before using the codes - which of course I can do but I was thinking of doing it in one go. Thanks for the code though.